# Get post from all the categories which has a name in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to pull all the posts from the categories which has a name. I am using the theme Twenty Fourteen.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more ?

Comment: i am making blog in a wordpress site, the problem is the site is already using some post which has unnamed category or are Uncategorized, so i need to use only those post in my blog section which has a category with a name.

Comment: "I need to pull all the posts from the categories which has a name" - do you mean you have categories that don't have a name? I didn't think that was possible. As a rule of thumb, if your question only contains one or two sentences, it is probably not detailed enough for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Below can work :-

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query('cat=-1'); // where -1 will be ID of Un-categorized category

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       if(get_the_title() != ""){ // this will check for blank name
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
      }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: i really appreciate your help

Comment: hey i am confussed and i sorry coz i am new to wordpress, but i need only those post which are not Uncategorized, so will this pull the title name or the category name

Comment: It will pull all the posts from each category. 
get_the_title() pulls title name

Comment: but i need to pull all posts which are categorized.

Comment: I have changed my answer